# Plotting a terrain basemap in R with ggplot (without a Google API key)

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, ggmap

I am looking to create a basic terrain base map of the Northern Hemisphere to later add lat, long points to. I don't want to use Google Cloud services to do this with an API, but I can't find a reliable way to plot a base map without requiring an API key. I have tried the 'basemapR' package with little success below:

```
#devtools::install_github('Chrisjb/basemapR')
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(ggplot2)
library(basemapR)

world_data = spData::world

ggplot() +
  base_map(st_bbox(world_data),basemap = 'hydda', increase_zoom = 2) +
  geom_sf(data = world_data, col = 1, fill = NA)+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-150,128), ylim = c(17,70))
```

I get the following error:

> Error in curl::curl_download(url, destfile = tmp) :
> Timeout was reached: [] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

I am open to other methods of getting a terrain base map and I am reaching out because I feel like this should have a simple solution that I cannot find. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need any specific projection, but you should be able to grab the map data from `map_data()` from the `maps` package.  There's some handy references online for how to do that.  Similarly the package `rnaturalearth` and `rnaturalearthdata` have some basic world data you can use to create a map.

Here's an example based on [this nice tutorial over at r-spatial.org](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

world <- ne_countries(scale='medium', returnclass = 'sf')

ggplot(world) + geom_sf() + coord_sf(ylim=c(0,90)) + labs(title="The Northern Hemisphere")
```

[image]

For some other nice references, you can check out [this page on DataNovia](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-map-using-ggplot2/) and [this one over at datavizpyr](https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-make-world-map-with-ggplot2-in-r/).

Comment: Thanks for those resources! Looking at the package documentation for rnaturalearthdata it is not clear if I can get a terrain map along with the country polygons. I am able to get the polygons (though I appreciate your example!) but I am specifically looking for a terrain map that shows topology. Have you had any experience integrating a more complex basemap with rnaturalearthdata?

Comment: Oooh... terrain map is a bit different.  If you have topology data that you can access, simply including lat/long + elevation, you should theoretically have no issue mapping that on top or under the polygons via `geom_raster()` or something similar, using the elevation as the fill color.

Comment: Topology data is available, such as GTOPO30 or similar - they are quite large though.  You can find some information from [the USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-digital-elevation-global-30-arc-second-elevation-gtopo30?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects) site.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and direction from @chemdork123 I was able to get the following solution for mapping a terrain basemap using ggmap. I also went further to plot points over the terrain map.

```
bbox <- c(left = -160, bottom = 15, right = 135, top = 70)

latitude = c(49.38639, 50.68870, 50.77530, 49.86880, 39.31181, 37.05229)          
longitude = c(-121.45063, -120.36646, 50, -97.40836, 76.71748, -119.19536)

site_df = as.data.frame(cbind(latitude,longitude))

site_map = ggmap(get_stamenmap(bbox, maptype = "terrain-background", zoom = 2))+
              geom_point(data = site_df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), 
               size = 1.5, color = "orange")+
              geom_point(data = site_df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), 
               pch= 21, size = 2, color = "black")+
              theme_bw() + 
              labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude")
```

[image]